# When we do a server side redirect, the new URL is called from the Client's IP or the Server's IP?

Tags: redirect, oauth, server-side-scripting

I have a scenario where my client machine's IP is not whitelisted for a staging server URL and my server's IP is whitelisted. So can I use server side redirect to show this URL on the client side?

Doing this is the javascript does not seem to work as this is client side redirect:

```
$.popupWindow('https://www.stage.abc.xyz.com:8443/webapps/auth/protocol/
```

- Can I show the "www.stage.abc.xyz.com:8443" on a client which is not
  whitelisted if I redirect to it on the server side from a server
  which is whitelisted?
- What IP does the URL's server see? The client's IP or the Server's
  IP?

Answer (score 0):

Will it be resolved if you can set a proxy server in your Server?